# Hyperledger Fabric. Cannot download Docker images using curl:

Tags: curl, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am installing Hyperledger Fabric Samples using [this manual](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html) and got stuck on this command:

```
curl -sSL https://some_address | bash
```

The first part of download is OK(the bin directory with some Hyperledger specific binaries) but docker images that should go next are not downloaded:

```
===> Downloading platform binaries
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.5M  100 22.5M    0     0  1342k      0  0:00:17  0:00:17 --:--:-- 2713k
===> Pulling fabric Images
==> FABRIC IMAGE: peer


Please login prior to pull:
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer


Please login prior to pull:
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Error response from daemon: No such image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: couchdb
```

I have a mac with Sierra version 10.12.6 and following version of curl (installed with brew install curl command):

```
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

My docker version is:

```
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
```

My docker info output:

```
michals-air:fabric-samples michal:$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.06.2-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170
runc version: 810190ceaa507aa2727d7ae6f4790c76ec150bd2
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.41-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.952GiB
Name: moby
ID: SLXT:JFLP:K2PF:Y3OR:DWGE:2RRG:FKKM:SGT5:UEAT:FMJP:RMIS:52BP
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 17
 Goroutines: 29
 System Time: 2017-09-30T11:49:45.528954264Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Can you try to run "docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.2" directly from a terminal on your mac?

Comment: And can you also post the output of "docker info"?

Comment: @Gari Singh, I tried the docker pull, but cannot log in with my docker credentials. (I should mention that I have no experience with docker). I have  put my docker info in the post.

Comment: You should not need to login to download these images.    Maybe try a "docker logout" and then try to do the "docker pull" again?

Comment: @Gari Singh - after putting docker logout I get a message: "Not logged in to https://index.docker.io/v1/"

Comment: I have changed my OS for my Hyperledger Fabric implementation from OSX to Ubuntu 16.04 and everything works just fine. BTW - I have found handy manual called "Fabric From Scratch - ffs" - https://github.com/kleniu/ffs_HLFv1.0

Comment: glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like an issue on your system than a generic one, piping the output to a known shell should make the context non-iteractive. I tried to run the steps just now and I was able to pull all the images. Can you update the docker to the latest or greater than 17.03-ce. I can see an issue raised on moby(open source docker) [1] for 17.03. Also please confirm if you are using any different registry which needs auth.

[1] https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31799

Following is the output of the curl command,

===================================================================

```
$ curl -sSL <<URL>> | bash

===> Downloading platform binaries
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.6M  100 22.6M    0     0  2187k      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 3514k
===> Pulling fabric Images
==> FABRIC IMAGE: peer

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-peer
d5c6f90da05d: Pull complete 
1300883d87d5: Pull complete 
c220aa3cfc1b: Pull complete 
2e9398f099dc: Pull complete 
dc27a084064f: Pull complete 
87675a6d4030: Pull complete 
93e601aafda8: Pull complete 
51fc526ed766: Pull complete 
e0386e9ee7cf: Pull complete 
a75d8afcee28: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ce6e3c3d0f71641020184e4fe0615c2e65b5181664bad3d05942091917b73e28
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-orderer
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
51fc526ed766: Already exists 
f5aa61fc7717: Pull complete 
ebcfc7becb40: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6427715d8c56b8778de30c7895287d0dd7bb9adb2f895337aac2dd3d0dcabca7
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: couchdb

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
6be6b5cbce6b: Pull complete 
c90d7a44426d: Pull complete 
9767b1c8440b: Pull complete 
b9b680c73863: Pull complete 
910808d7b46d: Pull complete 
b2b400af2b65: Pull complete 
656c0e3d1026: Pull complete 
fd537a07cc88: Pull complete 
fb80790f85e2: Pull complete 
6b4be879a573: Pull complete 
24e26e38b19c: Pull complete 
ba4d4ddd242e: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:5364d4f3e0844455195cc82626675cf01a873ba3b762d156efffb239740c2415
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: ccenv

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
6be6b5cbce6b: Already exists 
c90d7a44426d: Already exists 
9767b1c8440b: Already exists 
b9b680c73863: Already exists 
166a55562f41: Pull complete 
3d603cc86908: Pull complete 
5e68f74a4f28: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:3ad83a302e633dea8fa3d9d95b3e68919b7754d81bd521d1c3744bd251d5a526
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: javaenv

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-javaenv
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
6be6b5cbce6b: Already exists 
c90d7a44426d: Already exists 
9767b1c8440b: Already exists 
b9b680c73863: Already exists 
f27ca7df950b: Pull complete 
6bdffd82de79: Pull complete 
b049ece410a1: Pull complete 
d6a291b77d29: Pull complete 
7cb4541e382f: Pull complete 
b31b833bb285: Pull complete 
643fd0d667f7: Pull complete 
935ca4c299df: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:3cfb1ccb0b17e58a2a903a68959aa25e53dd3eaeefccd969944efd4b766541aa
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-javaenv:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: kafka

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-kafka
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
6be6b5cbce6b: Already exists 
c90d7a44426d: Already exists 
9767b1c8440b: Already exists 
b9b680c73863: Already exists 
acb25f369ac3: Pull complete 
16930d8f4113: Pull complete 
4641f537b20c: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ebbfd837ed010eac27007b7203074d3621969431e07fd6a874dc4c057bfbf0a2
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-kafka:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: zookeeper

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
6be6b5cbce6b: Already exists 
c90d7a44426d: Already exists 
9767b1c8440b: Already exists 
b9b680c73863: Already exists 
44885f365644: Pull complete 
46ece701894d: Pull complete 
2d416318c4a3: Pull complete 
f65b80d465e8: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ef981366251ad87d20f2d6de85f1c3524dd31d3551e6f53274925066c5b1d849
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:x86_64-1.0.2
==> FABRIC IMAGE: tools

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-tools
d5c6f90da05d: Already exists 
1300883d87d5: Already exists 
c220aa3cfc1b: Already exists 
2e9398f099dc: Already exists 
dc27a084064f: Already exists 
87675a6d4030: Already exists 
93e601aafda8: Already exists 
6be6b5cbce6b: Already exists 
c90d7a44426d: Already exists 
9767b1c8440b: Already exists 
b9b680c73863: Already exists 
0cb2dbc2f8a2: Pull complete 
05edc6c8e54b: Pull complete 
1a8edd3b0b2a: Pull complete 
579fce528924: Pull complete 
0c728eabbff4: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:9323ebacecc60f20562a49de201bd0a8b7852d3d9349a8916a66df1203fd38b0
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.2
===> Pulling fabric ca Image
==> FABRIC CA IMAGE

x86_64-1.0.2: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ca
aafe6b5e13de: Pull complete 
0a2b43a72660: Pull complete 
18bdd1e546d2: Pull complete 
8198342c3e05: Pull complete 
f56970a44fd4: Pull complete 
e32b597e7839: Pull complete 
a6e362fc71c4: Pull complete 
b42cff702f8a: Pull complete 
fd742d0d9134: Pull complete 
1af663083463: Pull complete 
aeef9e452233: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:25ab46a951c17b3034b3555b339ba4a985148668959f96152a1e91bbd1c7dd57
Status: Downloaded newer image for hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.2

===> List out hyperledger docker images
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                            latest              7e53be14f804        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                                            x86_64-1.0.2        7e53be14f804        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                         latest              ba9750b2565d        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                                         x86_64-1.0.2        ba9750b2565d        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                       latest              3f922f54bd68        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                       x86_64-1.0.2        3f922f54bd68        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                                         latest              0b4b1d249e65        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka                                         x86_64-1.0.2        0b4b1d249e65        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper                                     latest              1efb063147d3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper                                     x86_64-1.0.2        1efb063147d3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                       latest              6efd17e86e65        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer                                       x86_64-1.0.2        6efd17e86e65        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                          latest              0e2ed51971c9        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer                                          x86_64-1.0.2        0e2ed51971c9        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv                                       latest              0be45dbd7ff4        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv                                       x86_64-1.0.2        0be45dbd7ff4        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                         latest              d0f166e1a89e        3 weeks ago         1.28GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                                         x86_64-1.0.2        d0f166e1a89e        3 weeks ago         1.28GB

===================================================================

$curl --version

curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Comment: coolsvap, thank you for you research.  I have the newest version of docker for mac - 17.06. You are right that it's something on my osx - I tried this command on Ubuntu on vbox and it worked.